# Why does bytes.fromhex() produce the output shown?

Tags: python

I was wondering why this hex:
`bytes.fromhex("34 FF FA A3 A5")`
gives an output: `b'4\xff\xfa\xa3\xa5'`.  Why `\x` disappeared, shouldn't it be `\x34`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's how `bytes` `repr`s work; when a byte has an ordinal value corresponding to a printable ASCII character, it's represented as the ASCII character, rather than the `\x` escape code. You can create the `bytes` with either form (`b'4' == b'\x34'` is `True`; they produce the exact same `bytes` value), but it chooses the ASCII display to make byte strings that happen to be ASCII more readable (and make many `repr`s shorter).

Answer (score 1):

Python tries to print a good looking equivalent.
In your case we have: `'0x34'= hex(ord("4"))` , which means Unicode integer representing of 4 in hex equals '0x34'.
Try this one in your console: `print ("\x09")` . That's because \x09 in hex format represents \t.

Comment: Kind of a terrible test case; printing a tab character that's immediately followed by a newline is going to be indistinguishable from printing just the newline most of the time.

Comment: It shows how python acts in printing strings. It's not about indistinguishability.

Comment: Except you're printing a string, not its `repr` (or the `repr` of a `bytes` object). So you don't actually *see* `\t`, you'd see (or more precisely, won't see) a literal tab printed out. The problem is that you've come up with a demonstration that won't visibly demonstrate much of anything.

Comment: That's the point, you see nothing but "\x09" was printed and it was expected to be seen in console!

Comment: Okay, sure, but how is that any different from printing `'\x34'` (as in the OP's example) and seeing `4`? Or using some other printable character so you know a `print` really occurred, not just that something went terribly wrong?